# Local system over $\mathcal A_{g,[n]}$ with unipotent monodromy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let  $\mathcal A_{g,[n]}$ denote the moduli space of principal polarized abelian varieties with level-[n] structure and
$\bar {\mathcal A}_{g,[n]}\supset \mathcal A_{g,[n]}$ a smooth Toroida compapctification.
  For $n$ sufficiently large,
$\mathcal A_{g,[n]}$  carries a a universal family
$$h: X\to  \mathcal A_{g,[n]}.$$
Consider the  universal  locally constant sheaf
$$\mathbb V=R^1h_*\mathbb Z_{\mathcal A_{g,[n]}}.$$

My question is that, whether there exists an $n$ (largely enough), such that $\mathbb V$
  has unipotent local monodromy
around all components of $\Delta:=\bar {\mathcal A}_{g,[n]}\setminus \mathcal A_{g,[n]}.$
Is there any reference for this question?